# Lazy initialized variable holding a function swift

Tags: swift, oop, uiviewcontroller, lazy-initialization

I have a question in regards to how I would do a lazy initialization of a class variable that holds a function. In the project I am working on - in a view controller - I need to run a function based on information that I will only know after the view controller is created. Hence, I wanted to use a lazy initialization to solve this problem. I suppose I could solve the problem other ways, but now I am curious about what I am not understanding about lazy initialization that I am have such difficulty in figuring out how to get a lazily initialized variable to hold a function. That is, if it can be done at all.

Here is some example code of what I am trying to do. I want to be able to call `talk()` on an instance of `TestClass` and then this instance (`tc` in this case) call `f()` which is either `foo` or `bar` depending on circumstances.

```
class TestClass {

    func foo() {
        println("foo")
    }

    func bar() {
        println("bar")
    }

    lazy var f: ()->() = {
        return foo
    }()

    func talk() {
        f()
    }
}

var tc = TestClass()
tc.f()
```

Now, this doesn't compile and I get the error:

```
Playground execution failed: swiftTesting.playground:28:30: error: 'TestClass -> () -> ()' is not convertible to '() -> ()'
    lazy var f: ()->() = {
```

Then I tried changing my `f` lazy var to:

```
    lazy var f: TestClass->()->() = {
        return foo
    }()
```

This again did not work and now I get the error, `Missing argument for parameter #1 in call`.

Can anyone shed some light on how to do lazy initialization with a variable containing a function? I know that I could work around this by not using lazy initialization but I am hoping that someone can help me understand what I am doing wrong in this situation. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`foo` is an instance method, but closures avoid implicit capture of `self` by not automatically binding to it. You need to explicitly say `self.foo`.

```
lazy var f: ()->() = {
    return self.foo
}()
tc.f()
// tc is leaked, see below
```

When you instead used `TestClass->()->()`, the method is not bound to anything, so you need to give it an instance.

```
lazy var f: TestClass->()->() = {
    return foo
}()
tc.f(tc)()  // Call f with tc to give it an instance, then call the result
```

The first choice looks ok, but it will actually prevent `tc` from being deallocated. Binding `foo` to `self` and storing it inside `self` causes a reference cycle. To avoid this, you need to use a closure with weak capture of self.

```
lazy var f: ()->() = {
    [weak self] in
    self!.foo()  // ! because self is optional due to being weak
}  // no () here
tc.f()
// tc can be deallocated
```

Comment: Thanks for the great response. I did not realize the reference cycle I was creating in this situation. Just one thing you might want to update on your answer, it should be `return self!.foo` instead on the last piece of code. Is it also possible you could explain why you need the exclamation point when you use `[weak self] in` and you don't have to when you don't? Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

You need to explictly state `self`:

```
lazy var f: ()->() = {
    return self.foo
}()
```